# How to convert Python dictionary syntax from 2.7 to 2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-2.x, python-2.6

I am trying to run my script from Jenkins which has Python 2.6 installed. My script was originally written on a Linux machine which uses 2.7.5. Whenever I run the script form my local machine it works fine, but when I try to run it from Jenkins, it throws a syntax error for the following code:

```
rpmDict = {rpmList[i]: rpmList_full[i] for i in range (len(rpmList))}

rpmDataDict = {rpmDataTextList[i]: rpmDataTextList_full[i] for i in range (len(rpmDataTextList))}
```

Can someone help me translate this to 2.6 syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in *both versions* this is totally over-engineered.

```
rpmDict = {rpmList[i]: rpmList_full[i] for i in range (len(rpmList))}
```

Should just be:

```
rpmDict = dict(zip(rpmList, rpmList_full))
```

And:

```
rpmDataDict = {rpmDataTextList[i]: rpmDataTextList_full[i] for i in range (len(rpmDataTextList))}
```

Should just be:

```
rpmDataDict = dict(zip(rpmDataTextList, rpmDataTextList_full))
```

But as the other answer has noted, in Python2.6,

```
{expression0: expression1 for whatever in some_iterable}
```

Can be converted into

```
dict((expression0, expression1) for whatever in some_iterable)
```

Note also, you really should be using Python 3 as much as possible. In any case, in Python 2, use:

```
from future_builtins import zip
```

So that `zip` creates an iterator, not a list, which is more efficient, especially for larger data.

Comment: Was about to post the same basic answer (just with an intermediate step of `zip`+genexpr), up-voted yours instead. Just wanted to note that `from future_builtins import zip` avoids making a pointless temporary `list` from `zip` on Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `dict` constructor and pass it a generator expression of tuples:

```
rpmDict = dict((rpmList[i], rpmList_full[i]) for i in range(len(rpmlist)))
```